# Visual Studio 2012 showing directory listing rather than PHP website

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

With Visual Studio 2012 and PHP 5.4.14 For IIS Express installed when I open an existing PHP web site and select run I get a Directory Listing rather than index.php. When I create a new web project with index.php and select run everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this happens because Visual Studio is not properly loading IIS Express. You need to enable IIS Express by selecting Website -> Use IIS Express and then selecting run.

[image]